# Why does my background image disappear when I make its position fixed?

Tags: javascript, css, animation, css-position

Ok, my goal is to animate the background image with it sliding up from the bottom when the page loads and once the animation is over set its position to fixed. As far as I can tell the code I've written should work perfectly (I'm pretty new though), but when the animation ends and the javascript adds the position property to the background image, it disappears completely and everything below it moves up to take its place. Can anybody tell me what's wrong with my code?

HTML:

```
<div style="background-image: url(/resources/css/img/Logo\ Cropped.jpg);" class="background__img--hero"></div>` (set inside the header)
```

CSS:

```
@keyframes slideUp {
    from {
        margin-top: 700px;
    }
    to {
        margin-top: 0px;
    }
}

.background__img--hero {
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    height: 100vh;
    animation: slideUp 2s ease-out;
}
```

Javascript:

```
document.querySelector('.background__img--hero').addEventListener('animationend', posFix);

function posFix() { document.querySelector('.background__img--hero').style.position = 'fixed'; };
```

Comment: I think your <div> with the background image needs to have a width.

Comment: What do you need "position: fixed" for?

Comment: you just need to add a width to your img. `width: 100%`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At your .background__img--hero, just add these:

```
.background__img--hero {
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    animation: slideUp 2s 1 ease-out forwards;
}
```

or any width you want your image to have

Comment: Thanks for the advice! So it turns out I was stuck in a brain fart and mixing up position:fixed and background-attachment: fixed. Now that I've switched that out and implemented your advice everything works perfectly!

Comment: @dprozz122 I'm glad you found it here! Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

To animate the position of a `position:fixed` element, don't animate *margins*, but animate the position itself (in this cas `top`), like

```
@keyframes slideUp {
    from {
        top: 700px;
    }
    to {
        top: 0px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, so it turns out I was having a bit of a brain fart and mixed up position:fixed and background-attachment:fixed. Now that I've fixed that everything works as it should! It works regardless of if I use top or margin-top, is there any advantage to using top other than saving keystrokes now that I'm not dealing with the position property? I appreciate the help!